# Positive integers $(x,y)$ their sum and product is a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any genuine approach to find pair of positive integers $(x,y)$ such that both their sum and product is a perfect square?

One pair is $(5,20)$ but it looks to me that this question can be solved by hit and trial only which is very difficult thing to do.

Comment: To find one pair? A perhaps more natural one is $x=3^2$ and $y=4^2$, or use some other Pythagorean triple, but the $(3,4,5)$ is most familiar. Are you supposed to find just one example, or "characterize" them all?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well original questions says. "Find the number of such pairs". So I think there won't be many such pairs.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But we can generate as many Pythagorean triplets as we want as suggested by you. So it looks like generalization is not possible here. Am I correct?

Comment: There are infinitely many, you can even get infinitely many from your $5,20$ by multiplying each by any perfect square. So unless they put restrictions (like numbers must be under $100$) the number is infinite. The *exact* wording of the question would be helpful.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Exact Question: There is a pair of positive integers $(x,y)$. Such that there sum and product is a square number. 
Find the number of such pairs and also 
Prove that $3$ cannot be one of the numbers.

Comment: The proof that $3$ cannot be one of the numbers is not hard, a couple of lines, a small amount of number theory. We will use the fact that $k^2+1$ is never divisible by $3$.

Comment: The squares of any pythagorean triples...

Answer (score 3):

Let $\gcd(x,y)=G$.

Then, $x=aG, y=bG$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Note that $xy=abG^2=t^2$

This implies that $a$ and $b$ are both squares.

Let $a=X^2, b=Y^2$.

Then, $G(X^2+Y^2)=k^2$.

I) If $G$ is a square

This implies that $x,y$ are both squares, and that $X=(p^2-q^2), Y=2pq$ where $p$, $q$ are coprime integers and $p \not \equiv q \pmod 2$($\because$[Pythagorean Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)).

II)If $G$ is not a square

Let $G=n^2m$ where $m$ is a squarefree integer.

This also implies that $X^2+Y^2=mS^2$

Note that if $X^2+Y^2=a^2b$, $b$ is a square free integer, and $b$ has only prime divisors of the form $4l+1$ (from [Fermat`s Theorem on the Sum of two Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)) as $X,Y$ are coprime.

This implies that $m$ also has only prime divisors that are of the form $4l+1$, as $(X^2+Y^2)m$ is a square.

Since $m$ can be represented as a sum of two squares, let $m=a_1^2+a_2^2$

By multiplying $a_1^2+a_2^2$ to both sides, note that we must prove that $(a_1X-a_2Y)^2+(a_2X+a_1Y)^2=(mS)^2$

This implies that $(a_1X-a_2Y,a_2X+a_1Y,mS)$ are Pythagorean triples.

I suggest you proceed with calculations from here.

Comment: Is my solution correct?